# Can I display GIT in prompt when current directory has a .git folder?

Tags: bash, git, prompt

Can I display GIT in prompt when current directory **has/contains** a `.git` folder?   Is there a way to do this?   My current prompt is defined like so:

```
export PS1="[\u@\h] \w $ "
```

So, my prompt looks like this:

```
[user@computer] ~/workspace  $
```

And I want it to dynamically look like this:

```
[user@computer] ~/workspace GIT $
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/mikeweilgart/git-aware-prompt) and the various related forks.

Comment: A simpler workaround might be to use your shell's prompt-command feature to reset PS1 appropriately

Comment: @Wildcard I use that repo! I use `cat @ mint-kitty : ~ $` normally, and `cat @ mint-kitty : ~/repo(branch??!) $` when I'm on a branch.

Comment: One neat bash prompt customization for git that I've seen is to display time since last commit along with the branch information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most standard way is to use `__git_ps1` directly from git. In Ubuntu, it is available in this path:

```
source /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
## source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
#PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\$ '
```

You can notice the added part `$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")`, which will notify you about the current state of repo -- current branch, ongoing rebases, merges and so on.

The file in Ubuntu is provided by `git` package:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
git: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
```

For fedora by `git-core` (with a bit different path):

```
rpm -qf /usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
git-core-2.5.5-1.fc23.x86_64
```

---

Your prompt will change from

```
[user@computer] ~/workspace $
```

to

```
[user@computer] ~/workspace (master)$
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my Ubuntu box (although the directory does, and it contains a lot of files.)

Comment: @Wildcard It probably depends on version. On my 15.10 it is provided by `git` package (as noted in modified answer).

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be happier with this: is there a .git folder here *or in one of my parent directories*?

```
in_git () { 
    local dir=$PWD
    until [[ $dir == / ]]; do 
        [[ -d "$dir/.git" ]] && return 0
        dir=$(dirname "$dir")
    done
    return 1
}
```

Then your prompt is

```
PS1='[\u@\h] \w $(in_git && echo "GIT ")\$ '
```

This will show the GIT indicator if you're in some subdirectory in your repo.

Comment: True enough, but then you might as well just use `git status >/dev/null 2>&1` and see if you get an error, and at that point you're just [reinventing the wheel](https://github.com/mikeweilgart/git-aware-prompt).

Comment: Also this will fail if you're *inside* a `.git` directory; it will falsely report that you're in a git repository even though many git commands will not work other than in the working tree.

Comment: @Wildcard Many commands that do not require a working tree *will* work, though, and it is useful to recognize bare repos. It is most certainly not a "false" report (well, maybe if you're deep inside the bare repo, but not immediately inside).

Comment: @jpmc26, okay, `s/falsely/misleadingly/`.  Most basic git users would think of "inside a git repo" as meaning "inside a git repo's working tree," even if they lacked the terminology to discuss this.  It's just something to be aware of.

Comment: @Wildcard git is not really a system where you want to be blissfully unaware of the internals. It does not do an excellent job of isolating you from the plumbing. This has benefits and drawbacks, but regardless of whether it's good or bad, it is a reality. There's nothing misleading about it if you have a rudimentary understanding of where git puts things and how bare repos differ from non-bare repos.

Comment: @jpmc26, fair enough.  That's not the only issue here; there are even cases wherein `.git` can be a regular file rather than a directory.  As I mentioned in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278212/135943), the `[ -d .git ]` test is only *mostly* correct.  (NB: My answer has those issues also, but the [git repo I linked](https://github.com/mikeweilgart/git-aware-prompt) handles these cases much better.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your answers!  I ended up up putting this in my .bash_profile (on Mac):

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your `PROMPT_COMMAND` as follows:

   ```
   PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; if [ -d .git ]; then ingitrepo='GIT '; else ingitrepo=''; fi"
   ```
2. Change your `PS1` as follows:

   ```
   PS1='[\u@\h] \w ${ingitrepo}\$ '
   ```

Note that single-quotes are used when setting `PS1` to prevent premature variable resolution, and also note that a backslash before `$` at the end of your `PS1` is recommended—it's the same as `$` unless you are `root`; then it becomes `#`.

Also note that `[ -d .git ]` is only *mostly* a valid test for whether you're in a git repository.  But for quick-and-dirty, and for your own personal use, it's not bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can install https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt Which will show  **dev ±**  where  ***±*** means git and ***dev*** is the git branch you are currently in.